# Set Custom Discord Status when running/starting a Program

Tags: python, c#, file, discord, status

I am working on a application, where it would be cool to change the Status of your Discord User you are currently logged in to. For example when i start the appplication then the Status should change to something like "Playing **Program**" and when you click on the User's Status then it should display the Image of the Program.

Now i wanted to ask if this is somehow possible to make and in which programming Languages is it makeable?

EDIT: Solved the Problem with pypresence

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not if a certain programming language can do this, but if the Discord API can do it or if you have to use other ways than the official API.

I would advise you to take a closer look at https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro first.

Answer (score 0):

In your startup, where `DiscordSocketClient` is available, you can use `SetGameAsync()`. This is for C# using Discord.NET.

To answer your question, I think any wrapper for Discord's API allows you to set the current playing game.